# XSL Transform - Conditional Removing of Empty Tags

Tags: xml, xslt

I have xsl to remove all empty tags, but I only want to remove empty tags if all tags for that section are empty. Take a look at my input file for example:

```
<NEWORDER>
<ID>1</ID>
<HEADER>
   <NMP>NAME PLATE</NMP>
   <ORDER>
     <USER_ID>USER ID</USER_ID>
     <PARTNER_ID>PARTNER ID</PARTNER_ID>
     <USER_REFERENCE>5555-55555555-5555</USER_REFERENCE>
     <PO_HEADER>
        <PO_NUMBER>5555-55555555-5555</PO_NUMBER>
        <PO_DATE>20170322</PO_DATE>
        <PO_TYPE>BT</PO_TYPE>
        <RELEASE_NBR></RELEASE_NBR>
        <CUST_ORDER_NBR>5555555555</CUST_ORDER_NBR>
        <CONTACT_NAME></CONTACT_NAME>
        <CONTACT_PHONE></CONTACT_PHONE>
        <TRANS_METHOD></TRANS_METHOD>
        <SHIP_COMP>SC</SHIP_COMP>
        <CURR_CODE>USD</CURR_CODE>
        <INCO_TERMS>FOB</INCO_TERMS>
        <NAMED_PLACE></NAMED_PLACE>
        <PAYMENT_METHOD>BT</PAYMENT_METHOD>
        <TERM_TYPE>555</TERM_TYPE>
        <TERM_DESC>NET 10 DAYS</TERM_DESC>
        <DEST_BRANCH>5555</DEST_BRANCH>
    </PO_HEADER>
    <PO_HEADER_NOTES>
      <TEXT1_QUAL></TEXT1_QUAL>
      <TEXT1_MSG></TEXT1_MSG>
    </PO_HEADER_NOTES>
  </ORDER>
 </HEADER>
</NEWORDER>
```

In this example I would want the output to only delete the "PO_HEADER_NOTES" section as all inner tags are empty. Example of expected output:

```
<NEWORDER>
<ID>1</ID>
<HEADER>
   <NMP>NAME PLATE</NMP>
   <ORDER>
     <USER_ID>USER ID</USER_ID>
     <PARTNER_ID>PARTNER ID</PARTNER_ID>
     <USER_REFERENCE>5555-55555555-5555</USER_REFERENCE>
     <PO_HEADER>
        <PO_NUMBER>5555-55555555-5555</PO_NUMBER>
        <PO_DATE>20170322</PO_DATE>
        <PO_TYPE>BT</PO_TYPE>
        <RELEASE_NBR></RELEASE_NBR>
        <CUST_ORDER_NBR>5555555555</CUST_ORDER_NBR>
        <CONTACT_NAME></CONTACT_NAME>
        <CONTACT_PHONE></CONTACT_PHONE>
        <TRANS_METHOD></TRANS_METHOD>
        <SHIP_COMP>SC</SHIP_COMP>
        <CURR_CODE>USD</CURR_CODE>
        <INCO_TERMS>FOB</INCO_TERMS>
        <NAMED_PLACE></NAMED_PLACE>
        <PAYMENT_METHOD>BT</PAYMENT_METHOD>
        <TERM_TYPE>555</TERM_TYPE>
        <TERM_DESC>NET 10 DAYS</TERM_DESC>
        <DEST_BRANCH>5555</DEST_BRANCH>
    </PO_HEADER>
  </ORDER>
 </HEADER>
</NEWORDER>
```

The xsl that I am using to delete all empty nodes is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
version="1.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:if test=". != '' or ./@* != ''">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:template>
       <xsl:template match="text() | comment() | processing-instruction()">
       <xsl:copy />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please advise. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I notice that, in your sample output, you keep the empty elements `<RELEASE_NBR>`, `<CONTACT_NAME>`, `<CONTACT_PHONE>`, `<TRANS_METHOD>`, and `<NAMED_PLACE>`.  Why do you keep these, but remove `<PO_HEADER_NOTES>`?  Do you keep the former because 1) they are children of `<PO_HEADER>`?  or because 2) they have no children of their own?  What's the distinction?

Comment: Hi Eirikr, I keep those, because I need those place holders. They will represent space when I transform the message. However, if all the nodes are empty, I do not need to send it at all.

Comment: still a bit unclear -- it _sounds_ like you want to keep empty elements, **if they have no children**.  Is that correct?

Comment: I want to delete elements whose children are null. If a parent node has children which some are null and some have data, then I want to keep the null tags. Does this help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I only want to remove empty tags if all tags for that section are
>   empty.

That's not a very clear requirement. Looking at the given example, it looks like it should be restated as: remove any element that (a) has children, but (b) does not contain any text nodes - either as direct children, or children of one of its descendants. This would be implemented as:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[* and not(descendant::text())]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NEWORDER>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <HEADER>
    <NMP>NAME PLATE</NMP>
    <ORDER>
      <USER_ID>USER ID</USER_ID>
      <PARTNER_ID>PARTNER ID</PARTNER_ID>
      <USER_REFERENCE>5555-55555555-5555</USER_REFERENCE>
      <PO_HEADER>
        <PO_NUMBER>5555-55555555-5555</PO_NUMBER>
        <PO_DATE>20170322</PO_DATE>
        <PO_TYPE>BT</PO_TYPE>
        <RELEASE_NBR/>
        <CUST_ORDER_NBR>5555555555</CUST_ORDER_NBR>
        <CONTACT_NAME/>
        <CONTACT_PHONE/>
        <TRANS_METHOD/>
        <SHIP_COMP>SC</SHIP_COMP>
        <CURR_CODE>USD</CURR_CODE>
        <INCO_TERMS>FOB</INCO_TERMS>
        <NAMED_PLACE/>
        <PAYMENT_METHOD>BT</PAYMENT_METHOD>
        <TERM_TYPE>555</TERM_TYPE>
        <TERM_DESC>NET 10 DAYS</TERM_DESC>
        <DEST_BRANCH>5555</DEST_BRANCH>
      </PO_HEADER>
    </ORDER>
  </HEADER>
</NEWORDER>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. However, I want to delete elements whose children are null. If a parent node has children which some are null and some have data, then I want to keep the null tags for that parent. Does this help?

Comment: The problem is that the term "null" can be interpreted in many ways - see if the edited answer satisfies your requirement.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Given your requirements, the following single template seems to fit the bill:

- Copies elements with text or attributes.
- For elements with no text or attributes:

  - Copies them if they have no children of their own.
  - Deletes them if they have children, but the children also have no text or attributes.

Note that this is slightly different from your sample XSLT -- for attributes, that only checked if an element's attributes evaluated to `''`, the empty string.  In my own experience, I have (rarely) run into cases where an element might have an empty-string attribute, and where that attribute needs to be maintained, so the code below accounts for that by checking for the *existence* of attributes, rather than just the *value* of attributes.  Tweak to match your requirements.

```
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:choose>
        <!-- Strip only if:
            1) Element has children.
            2) Nothing in the tree starting here contains any text or attributes. -->
        <xsl:when test="./* and not(descendant-or-self::*[text() or @*])"/>
        <!-- In all other cases, just copy over, and process children. -->
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <!-- Copies the element itself. -->
            <xsl:copy>
                <!-- Copies all attributes, if there are any. -->
                <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                <!-- Sends any children along for further processing. -->
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi Eirikr, I tried it but did not receive the intended results. I only want to delete if a node has children, and the children have no text. In my example above, I want to delete " <PO_HEADER_NOTES>" because all of  it's children have no text.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. Michael's solution above gave the results I was looking for.

Comment: @Toya, I'm curious now, what XSLT processor are you using?  My output matches yours almost identically -- the only difference is the cosmetic difference between `<TAG></TAG>` in your sample and `<TAG/>` in my output (which are functionally identical to any compliant XML processor).